# Normal Distribution mean

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, mean

What does it mean when we say "consider a normal distribution in variable $x$ whose mean is a linear function $Ay+b$ of second variable $y$"? As per my understanding there is 1 mean of a normal distribution.

Answer (score 5):

Consider a simple linear regression model:

$$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x + \epsilon,$$

$$\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \, \sigma^2)$$

Given $x$, the intercept and the slope, the distribution of $y$ is normal. That means that the residual term $\epsilon$ follows a normal distribution with mean $0$.

It is not wrong to say $y$ follows a normal distribution, as long as you accept a 'mean' that can take on different values depending on $x$:

$$y \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 \cdot x, \, \sigma^2)$$

*(I'm using the more commonly used notation, but in your question, $x$ and $y$ are reversed.)*

Comment: (Note that you have reversed the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the question: I'll use your convention.)  I'm not sure about the "misleading" part of this answer, because referring to a "conditional distribution" presupposes assumptions that are not in evidence, which include that $(x,y)$ is a random variable.  In many regression settings $x$ is not modeled as a random variable at all.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @whuber you're right, I removed that part

Answer (score 2):

Well for example, it could mean this

[image]

$\text{PDF}[\text{NormalDistribution}[2 y+1,1],x]$

In other words, chaining to another variable just adds a dimension to the problem. So, instead of a 2D plot line having a normal distribution, we have have a 3D plot surface with a 2D normal distribution in $y$ and $z$ corresponding to each $x$-axis value, where the mean value is located at $Ay+b$ and $x=Ay+b$. In terms of selecting that distribution for each $x$ that yields $y=\frac{x-b}{A}$.

Comment: Explanation for the picture would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps!

Comment: @Tim Your wish is my command. It is done.